# "Might + Have + Past Simple" Grammar

Tags: grammar

In a scene of The War with Grandpa, when the child could not hide his mischief, he says "I might have did that".

While it doesn't sound fiercely strange to my ears, I couldn't recognize the grammar and structure of this expression.

What form of modal usage is this? Can you share more examples?

Comment: It is simply a childish error for "I might have done that".

Comment: I'd even expect *I might of did that*.

Comment: That's probly what the script said. In speech you can't tell the difference between _might of_ and _might have_; that's why it's such a popular spelling -- people keep hearing it.

Comment: How old was the child, please? What language might a child of that age be expected to use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I might did that

This was wrong the modal verb MIGHT HAVE does not work using a past verb

The kid made a wrong saying  you might did that.

The correct way to use this modal verbs is:

personal noun + MIGHT HAVE + past participle

> Might has no participles and no infinitive form.
> There is no past tense but might have, followed by a past participle, is used for talking about past possibilities: The explosion might have been caused by a gas leak.

[more info](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/might_1#:%7E:text=Might%20has%20no%20participles%20and,caused%20by%20a%20gas%20leak.)